# Objective-C: passing a string parameter to tapgesture @selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

What I am trying to achieve is this: when I tap an specific UIImageView, the UITapGesture will pass a string into the tap method.

My code follows below: Imagine I have an UIImageView object there already, and when I tap this image, it will make a phone call,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapFirstGuy = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(makeCallToThisPerson:@"1234567")];
[imageViewOne addGestureRecognizer:tapFirstGuy];

- (void)makeCallToThisPerson:(NSString *)phoneNumber
{
    NSString *phoneNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNum]];
}
```

However, I am getting the following compile error: `@selector(makeCallToThisPerson:@"1234567");`

I cannot figure what is happening. Why can't I pass string to the private method?

Comment: The only thing that can be passed is the gesture recognizer itself, just like other target action methods.

Comment: Because selectors are in other words pointers to methods, not closures or blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *action* should be just the selector for a method whose signature must be "method that takes a single *id* parameter and returns *void*". The *id* parameter will (typically) be the object sending the message.

The *target* (the object the *action* is sent to) can use the *sender* parameter to extract  additional information if needed, but that additional information needs to be asked for. It isn't supplied gratis.

That is, your ImageView subclass might have methods like:

```
- (void)setPhoneNumber:(NSString *)phoneNumber; // set a phoneNumber property

- (void)prepareToBeTapped 
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapFirstGuy = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(makeCallToThisPerson:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:tapFirstGuy];
}

- (void)makeCallToThisPerson:(id)sender
{
    NSString *phoneURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", phoneNumber];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneURL]];
}
```

That is, it's not the *action* nor even the `UITapGestureRecognizer` that knows the phone number. The target must know (or be able to obtain) the phone number some other way, perhaps carrying it as a settable property.

Answer (score 6):

One more way you can try writing subclass of `UITapGestureRecognizer` like that below:-

```
@interface customTapGestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * phoneNumber;

@end


// customTapGestureRecognizer.m

@implementation customTapGestureRecognizer

@end


// =====================

....

customTapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[customTapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(makeCallToThisPerson:)];

singleTap.phoneNumber = @"1234567";


-(void) makeCallToThisPerson:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer {

customTapGestureRecognizer *tap = (customTapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer;

NSLog(@"phoneNumber : %@", tap.phoneNumber);

}
```

**Note:**- The advantages of writing subclass is that you can pass more number of data easily in your `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong, It's not a valid selector.

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapFirstGuy = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(makeCallToThisPerson:@"1234567")];
```

You need to change to this:

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapFirstGuy = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(makeCallToThisPerson:)];
```

In your methods the parameter will be the tapGesture, that's it:

```
 - (void)makeCallToThisPerson:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
```

You can do several things, in order to pas a parameter:

1.- Use de tag of the imageView, the tapGesture knows the view than it´s attached you can use the tag view:

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tapFirstGuy = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(makeCallToThisPerson:)];
         imageViewOne.tag = 1234567
        [imageViewOne addGestureRecognizer:tapFirstGuy];

- (void)makeCallToThisPerson:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture
 {
NSString *phoneNum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%ld",tapGesture.view.tag];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNum]];
 }
```

Other option, subclassing in order to attach a NSString to imageView as a new property.

Comment: I agree with everything in Onik's post except the bit about creating a category. You can't add storage to an object with a category.

Comment: @DuncanC is wright. Through category you can't add a new property (or instance variable) to an exist class, (My answer was to quickly and wrong in this point without doubt). I've fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@OnikIV's suggestion of using the tag would work fine if the value you want to pass is an integer.

If you want to pass a string however it won't work so well.

You could set the tag to a unique value, then in the gesture recoginizer's action method, convert the tag value to an NSNumber and use it as a key to look up a value in a dictionary of phone numbers.

Another other option is to use associative storage to attach strings to your image views. Associative Storage is a technique that lets you attach key/value pairs to any arbitrary NSObject.

I have a sample project called [**AssociativeStorageDemo**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/AssocitiveStorageDemo) on github that shows how to use it.